# Nginx not proxying using proxy_pass

Tags: python, nginx, flask, reverse-proxy, gunicorn

I've a setup with `nginx` at front, reverse proxying the requests to `gunicorn` running at port `8000`. For some reason nginx reverse proxying not forwarding requests to gunicorn. I haven't touched the `nginx.conf` and `conf.d` folder is empty. I removed the `default` configuration in `sites-available` directory. I created my won with the follwing content.

```
server {
    listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

and python app's content

```
# server.py

import flask


app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'I am running !'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1')
```

For host in `nginx` configuration and in python app I've used `127.0.0.1`, `0.0.0.0` and `193.162.144.136` (actual) entries but none of them work.

I'm getting the welcome page for nginx on port '80' but unable to get the output of app.

There are no errors in nginx log and if I manually visit port `8000` it does shows the app content.

I'm running app in gunicorn with following command `gunicorn server:app`.

Any help in this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe that the default nginx configuration for most systems only includes files in the sites-enabled directory, can you confirm that you have a file there and that it shows up as part of the configuration when you run `nginx -T`?

Comment: Did you restart nginx using `service nginx restart`?

Comment: @jpevarnek .. it was a stupid mistake, for `sites-enabled` directory I only renamed the `default` file to `_default` and didn't remove which was getting loaded. Removing this file solved the issue.
@TarunLalwani .. yes.

Thanks guys !